# A regularity result for a parabolic PDE? Want $u' \in L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $f \in L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$ and let $g \in L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$ satisfy 
$$0 < a \leq g(x,t) \leq b\quad\text{for all $(x,t)$}$$
$$\frac{dg}{dt} \in L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega).$$

We know that there exists a function $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)\cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ such that
$$\int_0^T \int_\Omega u'(t) \varphi(t) + \int_0^T \int_\Omega g(t)\nabla u(t) \nabla \varphi(t) = \int_0^T\int_\Omega f(t)\varphi(t)$$
for all $\varphi \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ and $u$ satisfies $u(0) = u_0$ for a given $u_0 \in L^2(\Omega)$.

My question is, if we know that $u_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, does it follow that $u' \in L^\infty((0,T) \times \Omega)$? I.e. do we have the expected regularity of $u$? We expect this because $f$ is appropriately regular and as is $u_0$ so we expect the same for $u'$.

If so can anyone refer me to a citation for this result? Thank you. If not, what additional smoothness do I need? Let us assume $\Omega$ is as nice as required.